Kernel headers for nic missing
I'm hoping there is a way to repair my linux env. I'm using Zorin but it's ubuntu under the hood. I never really had issue with the OS but after letting it sit for a month the network just quit. I went thru a lot of testing to fix it only to find the headers are missing. I'm not sure how that is possible being it worked fine for so long.
I ran the live CD and the network card is fine. but the live CD had no upgrade option. If I boot my OS and add a wifi lshw does not show it. If I add a new nic I get the same issue. If I add a usb to nic, I get the same issue. In all cases if I download the drivers they all give me the same issue when I try to make I get an error about missing files in /lib/modules/5-15-09-generic/build
From the best I can tell my kernel is missing the headers. I see there is a way to manual download them here http://old.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/ but I have no idea what headers I need.

why did you include the first three paragraphs? ... they are irrelevant clutter

the headers are required when you compile code ... you're barking up the wrong tree


reboot
hold shift
select my kernel

Now the nic works and I can update everything.

so, the network didn't just quit as you said
